# Git merge not showing conflicts when file is replaced

Tags: git, merge

I've been trying to do the following:

- working on test.txt on master
- commit & push
- create branch NEW and checkout to it
- replace test.txt with a new test.txt with different content
- checkout to master
- merge NEW
  The content of test.txt is completely overwritten with the content of test.txt from NEW.
  Why doesn't the merge show a conflict? I want to merge the content of test.txt from both branches.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You don’t seem to add and commit the changes before checking out master and merging?

Comment: The way you describe what you did, it seems like you created branch NEW off of master after having committed the changes there. If that's the case, there is no conflict to resolve, the commit on NEW says to change the latest version on master to this different version, so that's a clean merge. You would only get a conflict if NEW was branched off of master *before* you had made the changes to test.txt on master.

Answer (score 0):

You have made changes to test.txt on master branch and pushed the changes to master

Now index will be pointed to latest commit - commit changes of test.txt

After you have created a new branch and made changes to same file test.txt and tried to merge new branch to master it will not raise conflicts as both the index will be pointed to same commit.

You will get conflicts for below case not in the above case

```
git pull origin master

git branch Branch1
git branch Branch2
```

when you try

```
git branch

* master
Branch1
Branch2

git checkout Branch1
```

make change to test.txt and commit

```
git checkout master
git merge Branch1

git checkout Branch2
```

make change to test.txt and commit

```
git checkout master
git merge Branch2
```

When you try to merge Branch2 you will hit conflicts as both branch has modifications to the same file

Comment: Thx for the quick reply @Nataraja B, but I get the same unwanted result.
I'll give a small example:
test.txt on master
LINE 1
LINE 2
LINE 3
while on Branch1, I'm replacing test.txt with 
LINE 2.2

Go back to master and merge Branch1 results in
LINE 2.2

I would've expect:
LINE 1
LINE 2 or LINE 2.2 (conflict)
LINE 3